# Bug? Increasing memory usage per iteration when using findContours()

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to debug this for a month, sure it was my bad programming practise, but I think it may be a bug, so I'm asking here first before I report.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <sys/resource.h> // memory management.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Load frame from disk.
void readFrame(int frameNum, Mat &frame) {
    // Construct filenames
    Mat image;
    stringstream number, filename;

    number << setw(7) << setfill('0') << frameNum; // expecting over 1e10 images over the installation period.
    filename << "../images/store-" << number.str() << ".jpg"; // assumes jpegs!//
    cout << "Loading filename: " << filename.str() << endl;

    image = imread( filename.str() );

    if (image.empty() or !image.data) {
        cout << "Input image empty:\n";
    }

    frame = image.clone();
}

// Class to hold the perceptual chunks.
class percepUnit {

    public:
        cv::Mat image; // percept itself
        cv::Mat mask; // alpha channel

        // constructor method
        percepUnit(cv::Mat &ROI, cv::Mat &alpha, int ix, int iy, int iw, int ih, int area)  {
            image = ROI.clone();
            mask = alpha.clone();
        }
};

// Segment foreground from background
void segmentForeground(list<percepUnit*> &percepUnitsForeground, Mat &foreground, Mat &frame) {
    Mat contourImage = Mat(foreground.rows, foreground.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    int area;

    // The following causes strange spikes in memory usage:
    // find contours
    findContours(foreground, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {

        area = contourArea(contours[idx]);

        if (area > 100) {

            percepUnit *thisUnit = new percepUnit(frame, contourImage, 0, 0, 100,100, area);
            percepUnitsForeground.push_back(thisUnit); // Append to percepUnits
        }
    }

    /* The following does not:
    findContours(foreground, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
        area = contourArea(contours[idx]);
    }*/

    /* Neither does this:
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
        percepUnit *thisUnit = new percepUnit(frame, contourImage, 0, 0, 100,100, area);
        percepUnitsForeground.push_back(thisUnit); // Append to percepUnits
    }*/
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int frameCount = 78298; 
    Mat frame, foreground;
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 MOG2model;
    list<percepUnit*> scratchPercepUnitsForeground;

    // add rusage stuff
    struct rusage usage; // memory usage.

    for(int i=0; i<= 75; i++)
    {
        // run full segmenter here.  (background disabled)

        readFrame(frameCount, frame); // was frame = readFrame();

        // Only process if this frame actually loaded (non empty)
        if ( not frame.empty() ) {

            MOG2model(frame,foreground); // Update MOG2 model, downscale?

            // before we segment again clear scratch
            // TODO how to delete the actual memory allocated? Run delete on everything?
            for (list<percepUnit*>::iterator percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.begin(); 
                 percepIter != scratchPercepUnitsForeground.end();
                 percepIter++) {

                delete *percepIter; // delete what we point to.
                //percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.erase(percepIter); // remove the pointer itself, and update the iterator.
            }
            // Added with EDIT1
            scratchPercepUnitsForeground.clear();

            // Segment the foreground regions and generate boolImage to extract from background.
            segmentForeground(scratchPercepUnitsForeground, foreground, frame);

        }

        frameCount++;

        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
        cout << "DEBUG leakTest_bug_report " << i << " " << usage.ru_maxrss/1024.0 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you use the images available here (http://www.ekran.org/tmp/images.tar.gz), you will find that the program's memory usage increases, and it seems to increase with the number of foreground contours. Since I'm clearing my storage (scratchPercepUnitsForeground) for each frame, I don't see why there should be increasing memory usage. The segmentForeground() function should exit, deallocating all its used memory, for each frame. The memory usage should be constant over time since we only check memory usage after the function has exited. It seems something is being left over that I can't figure out.

If I run just the findContours() part without the percepUnit() constructor, memory usage is constant, as I expect. If I run just the percepUnit() constructor without findContours(), memory usage is constant. Memory usage increases only when I use both. See commented code in segmentForeground() above.

I've confirmed this issue on two of my machines (both AMD64, linux) and running opencv 2.4.6.1 and 2.4.5.

### EDIT1

Code above has been changed to include the suggestion below, and yet the problem persists.

Here is what the memory increase looks like:

[image: Memory Usage]
<sub>(source: [ekran.org](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/memory.png))</sub>

The red line is the increase of memory (which *is* correlated with the test images linked above) seen when findContours() and the constructor are both called. The stable lines below are the two cases where we run either findContours() or the constructor.

### Valgrind Output

```
==2055== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2055== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2055== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2055== Command: ./leakTest
==2055== 
==2055== 
==2055== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2055==     in use at exit: 217,751,704 bytes in 112 blocks
==2055==   total heap usage: 800,066 allocs, 799,954 frees, 29,269,767,865 bytes allocated
==2055== 
==2055== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x63A720A: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==2055==    by 0xA8BC050: libjpeg_general_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x1495E4AE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x14950888: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x1495E0EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x14950890: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x14971A6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x14950898: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x1499024F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149508A0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149610EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0xA8BC067: libjpeg_general_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2)
==2055==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==2055==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==2055==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==2055== 
==2055== 1,555,228 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x4E87A90: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECDBF1: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECE378: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4F52F7D: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x40253C: cv::Mat::clone() const (mat.hpp:335)
==2055==    by 0x4028D5: percepUnit::percepUnit(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int, int, int, int) (leakTest.cpp:43)
==2055==    by 0x401E0E: segmentForeground(std::list<percepUnit*, std::allocator<percepUnit*> >&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (leakTest.cpp:63)
==2055==    by 0x40202D: main (leakTest.cpp:114)
==2055== 
==2055== 37,325,024 bytes in 8 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 9 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x4E87A90: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECDBF1: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECE378: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4F52F7D: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x40253C: cv::Mat::clone() const (mat.hpp:335)
==2055==    by 0x402897: percepUnit::percepUnit(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int, int, int, int) (leakTest.cpp:42)
==2055==    by 0x401E0E: segmentForeground(std::list<percepUnit*, std::allocator<percepUnit*> >&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (leakTest.cpp:63)
==2055==    by 0x40202D: main (leakTest.cpp:114)
==2055== 
==2055== 52,877,752 bytes in 34 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 10 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x4E87A90: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECDBF1: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECE378: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4F52F7D: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x40253C: cv::Mat::clone() const (mat.hpp:335)
==2055==    by 0x4028D5: percepUnit::percepUnit(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int, int, int, int) (leakTest.cpp:43)
==2055==    by 0x401E0E: segmentForeground(std::list<percepUnit*, std::allocator<percepUnit*> >&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (leakTest.cpp:63)
==2055==    by 0x40202D: main (leakTest.cpp:114)
==2055== 
==2055== 125,971,956 bytes in 27 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 11 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x4E87A90: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECDBF1: cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4ECE378: cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x4F52F7D: cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const (in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.5)
==2055==    by 0x40253C: cv::Mat::clone() const (mat.hpp:335)
==2055==    by 0x402897: percepUnit::percepUnit(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int, int, int, int) (leakTest.cpp:42)
==2055==    by 0x401E0E: segmentForeground(std::list<percepUnit*, std::allocator<percepUnit*> >&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (leakTest.cpp:63)
==2055==    by 0x40202D: main (leakTest.cpp:114)
==2055== 
==2055== 178,856,428 (6,720 direct, 178,849,708 indirect) bytes in 35 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 12
==2055==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2055==    by 0x401DD3: segmentForeground(std::list<percepUnit*, std::allocator<percepUnit*> >&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) (leakTest.cpp:63)
==2055==    by 0x40202D: main (leakTest.cpp:114)
==2055== 
==2055== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2055==    definitely lost: 6,720 bytes in 35 blocks
==2055==    indirectly lost: 178,849,708 bytes in 61 blocks
==2055==      possibly lost: 38,880,252 bytes in 9 blocks
==2055==    still reachable: 15,024 bytes in 7 blocks
==2055==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2055== 
==2055== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2055== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

So basically this seems to tell us that there could be a problem in the percepUnit constructor that does clone(). Running the constructor without findContours() shows no memory increase (as stated above), which includes the use of "new". The jpeg reader has also been unit tested, no memory increase. So, the valgrind output does not seem to help at all.

This should be reproducible! Please make sure you can reproduce it before providing an answer.

### EDIT2 (revised code and valgrind output, removed pointer method)

Here I have changed the list from a list of pointers to a list of instances. The memory increase is confirmed.

```
#include <sys/resource.h> // memory management.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Load frame from disk.
void readFrame(int frameNum, Mat &frame) {
    // Construct filenames
    Mat image;
    stringstream number, filename;

    number << setw(7) << setfill('0') << frameNum; // expecting over 1e10 images over the installation period.
    filename << "../images/store-" << number.str() << ".jpg"; // assumes jpegs!//
    cout << "Loading filename: " << filename.str() << endl;

    image = imread( filename.str() );

    if (image.empty() or !image.data) {
        cout << "Input image empty:\n";
    }

    frame = image.clone();
}

// Class to hold the perceptual chunks.
class percepUnit {
    
    public:
        cv::Mat image; // percept itself
        cv::Mat mask; // alpha channel
        
        // constructor method
        percepUnit(cv::Mat &ROI, cv::Mat &alpha, int ix, int iy, int iw, int ih, int area)  {
            image = ROI.clone();
            mask = alpha.clone();
        }
};

// Segment foreground from background
void segmentForeground(list<percepUnit> &percepUnitsForeground, Mat &foreground, Mat &frame) {
    Mat contourImage = Mat(foreground.rows, foreground.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    int area;

    // The following causes strange spikes in memory usage:
    // find contours
    findContours(foreground, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {

        area = contourArea(contours[idx]);

        if (area > 100) {

            percepUnit thisUnit = percepUnit(frame, contourImage, 0, 0, 100,100, area);
            percepUnitsForeground.push_back(thisUnit); // Append to percepUnits
        }
    }

    /* The following does not:
    findContours(foreground, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
        area = contourArea(contours[idx]);
    }*/

    /* Neither does this:
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
        percepUnit thisUnit = percepUnit(frame, contourImage, 0, 0, 100,100, area);
        percepUnitsForeground.push_back(thisUnit); // Append to percepUnits
    }*/
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int frameCount = 78298; 
    Mat frame, foreground;
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 MOG2model;
    list<percepUnit> scratchPercepUnitsForeground;

    // add rusage stuff
    struct rusage usage; // memory usage.

    for(int i=0; i<= 75; i++)
    {
        // run full segmenter here.  (background disabled)
        
        readFrame(frameCount, frame); // was frame = readFrame();

        // Only process if this frame actually loaded (non empty)
        if ( not frame.empty() ) {

            MOG2model(frame,foreground); // Update MOG2 model, downscale?

            // before we segment again clear scratch
            scratchPercepUnitsForeground.clear();
    
            // Segment the foreground regions and generate boolImage to extract from background.
            segmentForeground(scratchPercepUnitsForeground, foreground, frame);

        }

        frameCount++;

        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
        cout << "DEBUG leakTest_bug_report " << i << " " << usage.ru_maxrss/1024.0 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the corresponding valgrind output:

```
==3562== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3562== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3562== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3562== Command: ./leakTest
==3562== 
==3562== 
==3562== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3562==     in use at exit: 15,024 bytes in 7 blocks
==3562==   total heap usage: 795,556 allocs, 795,549 frees, 29,269,731,785 bytes allocated
==3562== 
==3562== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x63A720A: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:76)
==3562==    by 0xA8BC050: libjpeg_general_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x1495E4AE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x14950888: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x1495E0EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x14950890: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x14971A6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x14950898: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x1499024F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149508A0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 2,072 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0x1495F675: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149610EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x149253B8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0.24.4)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 7
==3562==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3562==    by 0xA8BC067: libjpeg_general_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2)
==3562==    by 0x400F305: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:85)
==3562==    by 0x400F3DE: _dl_init (dl-init.c:52)
==3562==    by 0x40016E9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
==3562== 
==3562== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3562==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3562==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3562==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3562==    still reachable: 15,024 bytes in 7 blocks
==3562==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3562== 
==3562== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3562== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

And yet, memory still increases unexplainably: (the overall increase from the previous plot is due to running this test in valgrind.)

[image: memory usage]
<sub>(source: [ekran.org](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/memory2.png))</sub>

For the same code here is the massif output: http://www.ekran.org/tmp/massif.print.leak
The massif output for the non-leak case where findContours() is not called, only the percepUnit constructor: http://www.ekran.org/tmp/massif.print.noLeak

### EDIT3

It was suggested in the cross-thread (http://answers.opencv.org/question/19172/bug-increasing-memory-usage-per-iteration-when/) that I read proc rather than using the rusage method, and look at this, memory does not steadily increase: (!)

[image: memory usage]
<sub>(source: [ekran.org](http://www.ekran.org/tmp/memory_proc.png))</sub>

This does appear similar to the massif output!! So I guess I need to redo all my unit tests. Anyone have a reason I should not give up here and consider the issue rusage?

Comment: You should really consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for finding memory leaks, you'll see where the leaks are and save yourself a month of debugging

Comment: I'll add my valgrind output above. I had been using it, but found it useless because most of the output was generated by code that was confirmed not to leak, and I could see no way of telling where the actual problem is. Of course last time I used it the program was 5 times larger. Further comments above.

Comment: I can see this on Centos6. Tried upgrading to libpixman-1.so.0.32.4 and the same leak occurs. From Valgrind:


   2,064 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
   ==15199==    at 0x4A069EE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270) 
   ==15199==    by 0x5BA8B7A: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libpixman-1.so.0.32.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the fact that your graph profiling with `rusage` increases monotonically is suspect.

The documentation of `rusage` states:

> The maximum resident set size used, in kilobytes. That is, the maximum number of kilobytes of physical memory that processes used simultaneously.

Since you are likely gathering statistics for the same process, only across multiple images, the conclusion that `rusage` reports the maximum memory usage *across all images* makes sense.

Indeed, using a different profiling tool (Instruments on OS X) generates this graph showing current memory usage:

[image: Memory allocations]

Which is quite similar to your results using `proc`. I would conclude that `rusage` is not the profiling tool you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your for-loop for your ptr-list cleanup is skipping items due to having both an increment-clause (`percepIter++`) and an iterator reassignment in the loop body itself (the return value from the `erase()` call).

In other words, you're double-incrementing your iterator, skipping every even-slotted items.

I've marked it below:

```
        for (list<percepUnit*>::iterator percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.begin(); 
             percepIter != scratchPercepUnitsForeground.end();
             percepIter++) { // ADVANCES ITERATOR

            delete *percepIter; // delete what we point to.
            percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.erase(percepIter); // ADVANCES ITERATOR
        }
```

You can address this a number of ways. For example, by removing the increment expression from your for-loop:

```
       for (list<percepUnit*>::iterator percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.begin(); 
             percepIter != scratchPercepUnitsForeground.end();) {

            delete *percepIter; // delete what we point to.
            percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.erase(percepIter);
        }
```

Likewise, you can simply enumerate the list, then invoke the list `clear()` method once you've freed all the pointed-to objects.

```
       for (list<percepUnit*>::iterator percepIter = scratchPercepUnitsForeground.begin(); 
             percepIter != scratchPercepUnitsForeground.end();
             ++percepIter) 
        {
            delete *percepIter;
        }
        scratchPercepUnitsForeground.clear();
```

Personally, I prefer the latter if I had to choose one or the other. It is, among other things, faster, and imho more readable.

But were I coding this I'd use smart pointers, which would make this completely irrelevant, as you could simply fire `scratchPercepUnitsForeground.clear();` and be done with it. When the list content is cleared all the smart-pointer destructors would fire, and they in-turn would delete their objects for you. The concept is called Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, or RAII for short, and it simply means all things, including dynamic allocations, have scope-based lifetimes with automatic reclaiming of resources when scope exits. [You can read more about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Anyway, thats where there is *definitely* a leak, and a big one judging by the looks of things.

Comment: Thank you. I've cross posted this question here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/19172/bug-increasing-memory-usage-per-iteration-when/

Comment: See my comments regarding the similar answer. Unfortunately, this is not the cause of the problem. In fact the leak I see is much larger than what I save by applying your suggested fix. (See EDIT1 above). If you can reproduce what I see in the graph we can move forward.

Comment: @b a shame it didn't solve your problem, because both that poster and myself are quite-correct regarding this being an outright memory leak. Regardless of whether it is the leak you're looking for, you should either instance-level the vector, use smart pointers, or fix the leak as suggest by he/she and myself here. If I get the opportunity to run this I shall, but since I've neither your test data nor OpenCV installed on this rig, "reproducing" it will be far from a quick-turnaround.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time here. I am in no hurry, I found these issues in a much larger program over a month ago and have only now painstakingly gotten it town to a simple test case I can share. I'm literally at my wit's end, and have spoken to quite a few other more experienced C++ programmers. One of whom suggested I switch from my old list of instances to pointers! (I made the changes to prove that was not the problem). I agree that using a list of instances is much cleaner, but either way this weird problem persists.

Comment: @b I hate to ask this, but is the Valgrind output (and thanks for posting that) *after* after applying the changes I show here? I don't want to be chasing a red herring. The last one above the leak summary is the leak I believe wa identified here but I want to be sure. If possible (and when you get the chance), please apply the change described here and your cross-post and reshoot the valgrin session, updating the question in an EDIT addendum at the end. According to that dump, the `new` in `segmentForeground()` is the root of all evil, and this answer should address that at least.

Comment: Indeed changing the list of pointers to a list of instances cleaned up the valgrind output considerably, but the increase of memory persists. See EDIT2 above.

Comment: @b I'm not sure you noticed, but here **178,849,708** vs. **0** when it comes to indirect memory leaks is an improvement. The valgrind report now shows a 14-kilobyte static loss, and that I highly suspect is due to the startup-code of libjpeg. Like it or now, that skipping-every-other-block fix proposed here and on the cross-site posting plugged a HUGE hole. In you case, simply instance-leveling the container made iteration moot. I would totally go with that update if you are able.

Comment: @b.. in fact, look at the stack traces of the few "leaks" that are left. they're all from the dl_init load of the library. None of them are in your mainline code path. I'm even more than convinced now than before that failing to free those allocations in `segmentForeground()` (one way or another) was the problem.

Comment: I agree a hole was plugged in this change. The problem is that hole was caused by code I wrote to try and solve this problem in the first place! I still can't explain the increase of memory over time in the graph above. Memory usage should be a flat line, but is not when I use both findContours and the percpeUnit constructor together. The jumps in memory we see in the graphs do seem to correlate with the number of contours found. I don't see what else could be left in memory that correlates with the number of contours after segmentForeground exits.

Comment: @b.. Is the graph at the bottom of the question post-change that removed/resolve your dynamic allocation ? (and thanks for posting the updated ValGrind report. at least with the current code we can rule out that leak). It is *feasible* that you're experiencing heap fragmentation which ValGrind would *not* catch as-executed, but it would have to be a pretty extreme case.

Comment: yes the graph at the bottom is the actual memory usage from the valgrind run (as reported by the code above). It shows the same pattern of increase, just uses more memory.

Comment: I'm reading the [OpenCV Memory Management](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html) page now. It seems they really go out of their way to shallow-reference count near-everything, putting the onus on the caller to know when to generate clones. Very java-esque of them. Anyway, I'm still looking at your second sample as well. (Running this on my Mac is out of the question since I really don't feel like installing MacPorts). Are the comments concerning the two commented out loops at the bottom of your update still applicable (and what is `area` in the second?) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35953/discussion-between-b-and-whozcraig)

Comment: First these spikes as shown in the graph do require my test images, so if you use different images I can't know if its showing the same problem. Second, I've reconfirmed (using the latest code posted above) that if I run findContours() without the percepUnit constructor, or find the percepUnit constructor without findConoutrs(), memory is stable.

Comment: I've added massif output for leaking and nonleaking cases above.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question after googling what seems to be the same problem (valgrind reporting "still reachable" memory with a backtrace including _dl_init and libpixman-1). I'm using Fedora 18 64-bit. I managed to reproduce the problem with an absolutely minimal C executable and .so library... the C program has just a main function that returns 0, and the .so has just one function (never actually called), which also exits immediately with 0. Yet valgrind still reports 5 unfreed blocks totalling 10,360 bytes. I decided to post this in case some other poor soul has spent a month debugging the same problem! Whatever the bug is, it seems unlikely to be caused by an executable and library, both of which do nothing.

Comment: Does RSS increase over time?

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, the memory leak disappeared when I recompiled the executable and the.so file on Ubuntu 13.04 (GCC 4.7.3, compared to Fedora 18's GCC 4.7.2). I made no other changes so the problem definitely wasn't with my code. The fixed .so continued to be valgrind-perfect even after i transfered it back to the Fedora machine. I would suggest recompiling any/all shared objects you are using, with a newer version of gcc. As for the question of memory usage increasing over time, I don't know because my project is very small, allocates little memory and exits quickly.